# All my Unity projects contain blank compilation errors (only the timestamps), preventing any projects from working or importing correctly

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, filesystems

I really need some help. I was rearranging file locations and trying to clear up some space and somehow broke the ability for Unity to operate on my laptop. The pictures of the errors are below.

This all started when I was moving a completely functional unity project from an external SSD to my internal laptop SSD. I had to clear space for the size of the project and I must have deleted something important, but I have no clue how to tell what it is.

[Error seen when opening project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbpqM.png)

[Editor view after opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0eKn.png)

[Error when trying to attach a script to a GameObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAXgg.png)

[Error in editor log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC1KO.png)

Steps I've taken:

- I've restarted my computer several times.
- I've completely uninstalled all editor versions and the unity hub (twice), including deleting all local app data for unity, emptying the temp bin, and clearing the keys in the registry.
- I've started completely new projects, checked
  old ones that used to work, downloaded sample ones from unity learn
  just to make doubly sure that it's not me being dumb.

My current theory is that this has to do with me clearing some data from a National Instruments folder. I'm new to programming and just read online that these drivers are needed for .NET communication, but would this be why Unity keeps failing then?

This has all taken more than a few hours and I'm struggling to fix this if anyone has any suggestions, please. I'd really appreciate any insight.

Update: I'm able to make new scripts, objects, scenes, etc. but I can't attach any script components to game objects because "the script class can't be found"

Update #2: Checking the Editor logs shows that the Tundra build is failing, and the "93 items updated" matches the 93 errors that are shown. No idea what Tundra is, but that's something to look at now!

Update #3: fairly more certain it's something to do with the .NET interactions, but I'm completely unknowledgeable about this and worried about breaking this further

Comment: Check you haaven't changed the namespaces of any moved files, make sure files that are Unity specific are in the correct folders.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question in case another person finds this and has the same issue, but the problem wasn't .net related or anything I mentioned. I uninstalled anaconda which caused some issues with the Command Prompt, where it would close immediately after opening. Unity uses this for a number of processes, so that's what caused all the blank errors.

The solution is to delete the Microsoft Command Processor AutoRun key in the registry editor.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-empty-errors-on-every-project-unity-2021-3-2f1.1279124/

[Cmd crashes with exit code 1 after uninstalling anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335300/cmd-crashes-with-exit-code-1-after-uninstalling-anaconda)