# "code" command does not work in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

"code" command for VSCode does not work on Windows

- Have freshly reinstalled VSCode
- Confirmed permission of the scripts:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb613481(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#how-to-allow-scripts-to-run
- "code" command does not do anything still:

  ```
  (base) PS C:\Users\lemon> set-executionpolicy remotesigned
  (base) PS C:\Users\lemon> code
  (base) PS C:\Users\lemon> Get-ExecutionPolicy
  RemoteSigned
  (base) PS C:\Users\lemon>
  (base) PS C:\Users\lemon> code
  (base) PS C:\Users\lemon> code .
  (base) PS C:\Users\lemon>
  ```
- Confirmed system env:

  (base) PS C:\Users\lemon> $env:PATH
  C:\Users\lemon\miniconda3;C:\Users\lemon\miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\lemon\miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\lemon\miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\lemon\miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\lemon\miniconda3\bin;C:\Users\lemon\miniconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.0.8.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\platform-tools;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Roaming\npm;**C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin**
- List item

-Tried to invoke the script directly - no output.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin> ls


    目录: C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2023/9/14      5:55           2067 code
-a----         2023/9/14      6:21       16738736 code-tunnel.exe
-a----         2023/9/14      5:55            167 code.cmd


(base) PS C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin> ./code.cmd
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin> ./code
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin>
```

Running Code.exe can correctly create the editor window

Help:About output:

```
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

````
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon> code --disable-extensions
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon> code --verbose
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon> code --log debug
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon>```
````

The commands above seems have no output

```
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon> code
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon> code | ps
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon> where code
(base) PS C:\Users\lemon> get-command code

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     code.cmd                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Users\lemon\AppData\Local\Programs\...
```

May I get to know how to fix this?

Comment: I’ve never needed to look at the file layout of a vscode install, but ```code.exe``` is invoking *none* of the files you’ve listed - it’s finding that somewhere else. Check your PATH variable and see if the “bin” folder has crept in ahead of the location of “code.exe”. (I’m not sure what it’s *supposed.* to look like, but I can check on my machine later today and confirm…)

Comment: Also, do you see the same behaviour from a regular Windows Command Prompt, or does ```code``` launch vscode correctly?

Comment: Windows 11 22H2 seems not packaged with CMD. the "code" command alone in PowerShell does not do anything, even with "--verbose" flag.

Comment: Make sure that in VSCode you are running in the `PowerShell Extension` terminal that comes from the plugin, and not some other normal `pwsh` or `powershell` terminal. The `code` command only works in the `PowerShell Extension`

Comment: I can confirm my PATH contains the /bin folder, added to the main question

Comment: when you run `code` with the task manager open (try this a couple times), do you ever see VS Code appear at all as a process? What happens when you run `where code`? What do you see if you run `Get-Command code`?

Comment: Nope, there is no new process being forked. Also updated the results of commands input needed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone suffering the same issue as I do --

The problem actually is caused by the uninstallation of the Anaconda package manager:
[Cmd crashes with exit code 1 after uninstalling anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335300/cmd-crashes-with-exit-code-1-after-uninstalling-anaconda)

The process exited with code 1 is just too general and masked bunches of problem.

Comment: Please don’t use link as an answer. The page that mentioned changes in the future, please add the content directly from the link.