VSCode paths off after reinstalling miniconda
Due to an earlier mistake I made I ended up reinstalling miniconda for Windows. Now, my existing project having a custom env path works again but vscode seems to be off when trying to do the same.
In a git bash terminal it's all good:
user@machine MINGW64 /d/Users/<project-folder> (master)
$ conda activate ./conda
(D:\Users\<project-folder>\conda)
user@machine MINGW64 /d/Users/<project-folder> (master)
$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path.realpath(sys.executable)
'D:\\Users\\<project-folder>\\conda\\python.exe'
>>> import sqlite3
>>>

but running the same piece of code in my existing vscode project leads to a bunch of calls issued:
PS D:\Users\<project-folder>> C:/Users/<user>/miniconda3/Scripts/activate
PS D:\Users\<project-folder>> conda activate d:\Users\<project-folder>\conda
PS D:\Users\<project-folder>>  d:; cd 'd:\Users\<project-folder>'; & 'd:\Users\<project-folder>\conda\python.exe' 'c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '60781' '--' 'D:\Users\<project-folder>/main.py'

main.py prints the executable path and then imports sqlite3 which leads to a crash.
D:\Users\<project-folder>\conda\python.exe
Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: Module not found.
  File "D:\Users\<project-folder>\main.py", line 37, in <module>
    import sqlite3
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: Module not found

So apparently vscode activates the environment but it still can't find sqlite3.dll upon trying to import the library. The only difference seems to be that vscode activates the environment through the use of absolute paths which I have found no way of changing but I assume this is not the problem here.
Digging a bit deeper I can see that the environment's path variables are not set in vscode. There should be the following ones set:
D:\Users\<project-folder>\conda
D:\Users\<project-folder>\conda\Library\bin
D:\Users\<project-folder>\conda\Library\mingw-w64\bin
D:\Users\<project-folder>\conda\Library\usr\bin
D:\Users\<project-folder>\conda\Scripts
D:\Users\<project-folder>\conda\bin

One of them contains the sqlite3.dll file that can't be found. Crucially, they are in fact set when using the git bash terminal. Making them part of PATH statically solves the problem but it wouldn't allow me to switch between the various environments I use across other vscode projects.
I wonder what I can do to make them dynamically available when vscode tries to automatically enable the environment? It would be great to come back to the way of working I had before the miniconda reinstall.
Did I mess up the settings when reinstalling miniconda3? I vaguely recall some options about PATH...
btw: My way of starting vscode is through the Windows start menu. I could use the anaconda prompt, activate the environment manually and then run code . but of course this is a bit inconvenient.

I may have found a solution following this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67298127/2220850
running conda init from inside a vscode terminal first leads to an issue about power shell security policies. Those can be circumvented via
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser

from a Windows PowerShell as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.4
A safer way appears to be described here but I was unable to test it since the above fix prevents me from reproducing the original problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66836989/2220850
